# Changing enum value in Rails without saving model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, active-enum

How do I change an enum value without saving the model to the database yet?

The documentation for [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) indicates that methods like `conversation.active!` and `conversation.status = "archived"` is equivalent to doing `conversation.update! status: 1`, whereas I'm getting attributes from a simple_form form, and I don't want to save the model until all of the attributes have been set, as otherwise the model won't be valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bang version of the method - `conversation.active!` will save to the database immediately.

The other way - `conversation.status = "archived"` will not, and will require an explicit `conversation.save!` afterwards. So, that's the method you're after.

(BTW, the rails console is really handy for testing stuff like this, and will even show you the exact sql that gets executed with the bang version of the method, as you execute it)

Comment: So it is! So the comment in the documentation saying `# conversation.update! status: 1` is incorrect?

Comment: Yeah. You'd have to do `conversation.status = "archived"; conversation.save!`